# Rate Limited By Google Maps But Not Exceeding Limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I am using promises to limit my requests to the client side Maps Direction API. Google's documentation says I can perform 10 requests every second but I can't do this and I'm not sure why.

I am performing 18 calls over approx 20 secs every 3 minutes and I'm getting rate limited the first round every single time.

Now obviously 18 calls in 20 seconds is a lot less than 10 per sec. Am I reading the wrong information? Or misunderstanding how all of this works? Any help is appreciated I've been at this for too long now.

Here is a fiddle I've created to simulate what I'm doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/ffauf2bf/1/

Instead of 18 calls every 3 minutes I've set it to run once a minute. If you open your console you can see that status of each call as well as the second and millisecond at which it was called. You'll also notice that the first round of calls is always rated limited, while each subsequent round of calls is successful despite no difference between each "round".

I hope this makes sense! If you have any questions I'll be happy to clarify. In case you don't want to/can't visit jfiddle I will include relevant code below

```
const getDistance = async (people, place) => {
  await sleep(500);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let origins = [];
    for(let person of people){
      origins.push(new google.maps.LatLng(person.lat, person.lng));
    }
    const destin = new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng);
    const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
        origins: origins,
        destinations: [destin],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, (res, status) => {
        if(status === "OK"){
          console.log(
            status, `${new Date().getSeconds()}:${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`
          );
          let result = {id: place.id, distances: []}
          res.rows.forEach((row, i) => {
          result.distances.push(
                {id: people[i].id, distance: row.elements[0].status}
            );
          });
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(status);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

which is called by:

```
const findClosest = () => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    let result = [];
    for (let place of places){
      try {
        let distances = await getDistance(people, place);
        result.push(distances);
      } catch(e) {
        reject(e);
      }  
    }
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe you are hitting the limit because of your number of elements. According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix, Note: each query sent to the Distance Matrix service is limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements.

Comment: The fiddle is working for me (I don't see any failures).

Comment: Did you read the "Note" under "Usage limits and policies" in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#UsageLimits)?

Comment: @geocodezip that's super weird...  the first one fails for me every single time. I am not exceeding 100 elements per second and I am not exceeding 10 requests per second and there are no other users sharing my key

Comment: I understand why I'm receiving the error fundamentally but to me it doesn't seem like I'm going over any quotas. If I send 12 elements every 250ms thats only 48 elements per second and 4 requests per second so it should work every single time but it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this, I have found a solution.

The problem was the way I was attempting to throttle my network requests. Using this

```
const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

was incorrect. By forcing my code to wait like this I was seeing behavior where two functions might still end up firing at the same time.

Instead I switched to using lodash, specifically the `throttle` function.

By doing this

```
const asyncFunc = _.throttle(asyncFunc, 250);
```

You guarantee that the function will not be called more than once every 250ms.